# How to set focus following setting Form Filter that returns zero records

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, setfocus

I have a textbox control in the header of a continuous form. Characters entered are used to build and apply a filter string. Once the filter is applied the focus is set back to the textbox using set focus and selstart so the user is able to add more characters. The result is the list of records is filtered as each character is entered.

The set filter code is triggered by the textbox on change event. The code moves focus to another control and then back so that the textbox.value property is updated (I tried using .text but kept running into other focus issues).

The record filtering works until a string is entered that results in zero records being displayed.
At this point the line of VBA that sets the Selstart property throws

> "you can't set a property of a control unless it has focus"

The lines of code are listed below, `TxtFilterString` is the name of the textbox, LengthOfText is an integer, SetFormFilter is a sub that builds the filter and applies it:

```
LengthOfText = Len(Me.TxtFilterString.Value)

SetFormFilter

Me.TxtFilterString.SetFocus
Me.TxtFilterString.SelStart = LengthOfText
```

It appears that the line `Me.TxtFilterString.SetFocus` fails when there are no records to display and this causes the following line to throw an error despite the control being visible in the header section.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have listbox displaying the results of your query.
If it errors when 0 records are displayed in the listbox then could you not put a simple check around the listbox results that doesn't run the line that errors?

```
if listbox.listcount >0 then
  Me.TxtFilterString.SelStart = LengthOfText
endif
```

Comment: Sorry if I have not been clear.  The text entered into the unbound text box is used to create a filter clause which is then applied to the form.  The form show continuous records and the problem occurs when there are no records to display. However, I have a work around which is similar to your suggestion and I will post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the problem occurs but my solution is to not execute the line of code if the record set is empty or the text box in question contains null which seems to happen if the contents are deleted using the delete key.  My on change sub is here:

```
Private Sub TxtFilterString_Change()
' Call sub that sets the form filter to value entered in text box
   Dim LengthOfText As Integer
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Me.CmdResetSearch.SetFocus  ' move the focus away to update the  value prop, as the text prop has focus issues
    Me.TxtFilterString.SetFocus

    SetFormFilter ' build and set the continuous forms filter string

    ' The following if block is to overcome a bug where Access does not allow the
    ' set focus property of the text field to be set when there are no records to display

    ' The result is that the filter string that returns zero records becomes highlighted
    ' allowing it to be overwritten.

    ' The IsNull clause is required if the user used delete to remove the text in the text box

   If Me.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Or IsNull(Me.TxtFilterString) Then
      ' There are no records or the user has deleted in the field (causing a Null to be enetered)
      Me.TxtFilterString.SetFocus

    Else
      ' There are records and there is text in the text box so set focus and caret position
      Me.TxtFilterString.SetFocus
      Me.TxtFilterString.SelStart = Len(Me.TxtFilterString.Value)
   End If

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "An error in TxtFilterString_change : " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```